# How to connect Django to remote MySQL database over ssh tunnel?

Tags: mysql, django, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have access to remote MySQL database using ssh tunnel with `host`, `user`, `password`.

I can access to database in MySQL Workbench using ssh tunnel with `SSH Hostname`, `SSH Username`, `SSH Password`.

Also I have access in Pycharm using ssh tunnel with `Host`, `User name`, `Password`.

I'm trying to connect Django to a MySQL database.
Is it possible to add SSH settings to these database settings in Django settings file and have access through Django?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
        'NAME': '<DATABASE NAME>',                     
        'USER': '<USER NAME>',
        'PASSWORD': '<PASSWORD>',
        'HOST': '<HOST>', 
        'PORT': '3306'    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by integrating [`sshtunnel`](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/) package.

If you have complete control over when the database connections are made, you can put the SSHTunnelForwarder wrapper around the SQL code, and any SQL code you do inside that with statement will be able to connect to the database -- but code outside that statement won't. So that doesn't help when you're using Django either, because its MySQL code is hidden deep inside the Django library and wrapping it with the with statement would be very tricky.